# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.spr.model.User

Tags: hibernate

I was getting a `ClassCastException`. While executing the below method:

```
public User getUserByEmail(String email){
Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(getByEmail);
query.setParameter("email", email);
return (User)query
}
```

My requirement is based on the email. I want to retrieve the user information, and the email is unique. How to do that using Query interface of hibernate? I want to return User object based on email parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
User user = (User)
    sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("select u from User u where u.email=:email")
           .setString("email", email)
           .uniqueResult();
```